# how to download ssh keypair from fi-lab cloud more than once?

Tags: ssh-keys, fiware, filab

I am starting with fi-lab Cloud at at http://lab.fi-ware.org, then I created security key pair before start to create an instance. Associating the floating ip address to an instance and using this key pair under a ssh session is the only way to have terminal access to the created instance:
1 - tab security > key pairs > create 
2 - given a name to keypair "kpname" 
3- resulting in:
 *The keypair "kpname" should download automatically. If not use the link below.

Download Keypair*

Well, the "automatically download" doesn't started on google chrome browser (windows 7 and mac os 10.8.5)
No problem, I clicked on the provided link (blob:https%3A//cloud.lab.fi-ware.org/850xxxsnipedxxxxecd4), get the "kpname.pem" file, changed the file mode permission (chmod 600) and used with ssh command.

The problem is when I need to use another computer and not keep the key file stored on my hands (pendrive, dropbox, email...). This way I cannot access my virtual machine, neither creating a new keypair from fi-lab cloud site, because there is no function to associate a new key pair in a created instance. The only place to associate the keypair is on the creation instance workflow. That is, creating a new instance.

I dont know where to click to download again the same keypair. If not exists I believe the platform could offer download keypair in the context menu (action) from each created key pair.

The only "action" from each keypair is to delete a selected keypair.

thanks for help.

Comment: Sorry, for it. For security reasons we cannot store the public keypair once that it is generated. The only action that I suggest is to copy it to the new machine. I know that it is not a valid solution for your case but at the moment we cannot give you another solutions.

Comment: ok. but what happens when I really lost a keypair? Is it really necessary  create a new virtual machine and restart all the job to install de generic enablers? how to inject a new keypair in a existent virtual machine?

about security, maybe in some next next release, because I understand it is a safe environment where the client makes login and only him is able to get the keypair. The responsible of that keypair is the authorized client. thanks.

Comment: No it does not be necessary, you should contact to the administrative team in order to resolve the issue. In that case, you should create a new keypair and with the help of the system administrator resolve the issue.